# If $\Vert \alpha(v) \Vert = \Vert v \Vert$ for all $v$ in an orthonormal basis does that mean $\alpha^{\star}\alpha = \sigma_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

More specifically than the title, let $\alpha : V \to V$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space. If $ \|\ \alpha(v) |\| = \|\ v \|\ $ for all $v$ in some orthonormal basis for $V$, must $\alpha$ be unitary?

I believe $\alpha$ must be unitary with these conditions. However, I'm not 100% convinced with my proof, I feel like I'm overlooking something.

Since $ \|\ \alpha(v) \|\ = \|\ v \|\ $, we have that for all $v \in V$,
$$ \langle \alpha(v), \alpha(v) \rangle = \langle v , v \rangle \iff \langle v , \alpha^{\star}\alpha(v) \rangle = \langle v , v \rangle $$
Since we're in an inner product space, it must be the case that,
$$\alpha^{\star}\alpha(v) = v \iff \alpha^{\star}\alpha = \sigma_{1}$$ 
and hence, $\alpha$ must be unitary.

Comment: what does $\alpha^{\star}$ mean ?

Comment: $\alpha^{\star}$ is the adjoint operator

Comment: Let $A$ denote the matrix of $\alpha$ with respect to some orthonormal basis of $V$, then $\alpha^{\star}$ denotes the Hermitian matrix of $A$.

Comment: Your notation is non-standard...to say the least. First, to denote linear operators with lower-case greek letters is unusual and may even be confusing , and second: is $\;\sigma_1=I=\;$ the identity operator?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, $\sigma_1$ is the identity operator.

Comment: Ok...but then what you wrote there one line after your second "Since" is false, as for that step to be true it must be so **for any** $\;v\in V\;$ and not only for those elements in some basis, orthonormal or otherwise.

Comment: @DonAntonio, what is the standard? I have only ever seen it denoted this way in class and in my text.

Comment: @JohnSmith Texts don't use that, as far as I am aware of. That's what I call "standard": what most people use. Not that yours is *wrong* : it is just unusual.

Comment: * for the adjoint is the usual way of writing it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $V = \mathbb R^2$ and $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, take the standard basis.

Comment: Is it counterexample?

Comment: @Parisina Yes, it satisfies the condition but is not unitary.

Comment: Are you sure is this counterexample? This matrix doesn't satisfy in the question assumption. I think his prove is correct, since $\alpha$ is an automorphism and since it's distance preserving, so $\alpha$ is unitary by the definition.

Comment: @Parisina Don't just claim something, prove it. Which vector out of the orthonormal basis I chose violates the assumption? There are only 2 possibilites: $\binom10$ and $\binom01$, please name it.

Comment: @Parisina LeBtz counter-example works fine. Thank you for that by the way. :-)

Comment: Let $v=(x,y)^T$, hence $\|\alpha(v)\|^2=\langle \alpha(v),\alpha(v)\rangle=(x+y)^2$ with dot product. smilarly, $\|v\|^2=\langle v,v\rangle=x^2+y^2$. I'm not sure how you say that $\|\alpha(v)\|^2=\|v\|^2$.

Comment: @JohnSmith I can show $\alpha$ is monic, since $\|\alpha(v)\|=\|v\|$, I can say $\|\alpha(v)\|=\|\sigma_1(v)\|$. Hence $ker(\alpha)=ker(\sigma_1)=\{0\}$, and since $V$ is finitely generated, so it's an automorphism. By our auumption $\alpha$ is isometry (it's distance preserving), so it's unitary. I guess this is a valid argument, and if my argument is not correct, I appreciate you let me know my mistakes.

Comment: @Parisina I already gave you an answer. Tell me which of the vectors $\binom 10$ or $\binom 01$ violates the assumption. It is that simple. Is it the first one or the second one?

Comment: Ok $\|(v)\|=\| v\| $  for all $v$ in some orthonormal basis for $V$. It was very smart answer. If it was true for all $v\in V$ I guess my argument was true. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your argument works if it is true for all $v\in V$.